# Are Mutexs Released behind the scenes if Stop Debugging is hit in VS15?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ide, mutex

I have run into an issue with the only mutex in my program. It is intended to ensure only one instance of my application can run at a time.

I believe I have caused the abandoned mutex exception by hitting the Stop Debugging (shift-f5)in Visual Studio 2015, which meant that the finally block was never called and the mutex was not released.

```
 static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "APP_NAME_COMPANY");

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), false))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Application already started!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
             //important things
        }

        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
```

Do you think hitting Stop Debugging is the culprit?

Comment: What's actually your question?

Comment: @dcg Are mutexs released behind the scenes if you hit Stop Debugging?

Comment: As I see it, it might or not, depending on how visual studio stops the process (your app). If it forces it to stop I don't think the `mutex` is released and if he asks nicely to stop maybe your program can get to release the `mutex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutex is released by the operating system, because your process has terminated (with "Stop Debugging").
However, the next time you use the same mutex, a `AbandonedMutexException`will be thrown. This is by design and shall notify you that last time the mutex was used, it was released in a improper way (in your case: By the process being killed by "Stop debugging").
However, this exception can be treated as a warning, and you can use the mutex afterwards as normal.

Comment: Is the exception thrown in your code when you restart the app?